# how to display quotes from .txt file to the activity

Tags: android, string, android-background

I am just a beginner for android. My application consists of number of images displaying quotes(having same background) . Now what i am doing is i have saved the quotes in the .txt file and placed in `/res/raw` folder . I am trying to display these quotes from the file to the activity but not getting any result. Any suggestions.

Comment: what are u doing for this?. u can paste .txt file in assests for try alternatively.

Comment: SQLite database is better way to achieve this my frnd... :)

Comment: how to do if i pasted it in assets folder ...

Comment: From assests u can easily read the file try a google search for this

Comment: i tried putting in asset folder first and implementing this code

Comment: AssetManager am = context.getAssets();
InputStream is = am.open("test.txt");

Comment: @BlackTigersir , i have no idea about the SQLite db ... by the time i am learning SQLite i am trying this

Answer (score 0):

Method to read from file:

```
  public byte[] readFileFromRaw(Context context, int fileId) throws IOException {
        Resources res = context.getResources();
        InputStream inputStream = res.openRawResource(fileId);

        int i = 0;
        while (inputStream.read() != -1) {
            i++;
        }

        inputStream.reset();
        byte[] b = new byte[i];
        inputStream.read(b);
        return b;
    }
```

Now you can use it in next way:

```
byte[] b = readFileFromRaw(this, R.raw.my_quotes);
```

If you need string just do that:

```
String quote = new String(b);
```